# How to instantiate input based strategy pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, pattern-matching

The instantiation of strategy pattern is usually completely overlooked by the examples. Let's assume there is an input that defines which class to use. We'd have something along the lines of:

```
class Strategy {
    Strategy(){}
    virtual void runAlgorithm() = 0;
};

class A : public Strategy {
    A () {}
    static bool isA(char input){ return input == 'A'; }
    void runAlgorithm { /* Do A algorithm */ }
};

class B : public Strategy {
    B () {}
    static bool isB(char input){ return input == 'B'; }
    void runAlgorithm { /* Do B algorithm */ }
};

// Other algorithms

Strategy* createStrat(char input){
    Strategy* instance;

    // Define which algorithm to use
    if (A::isA(input)) {
        instance = A();
    } else if (B::isB(input)) {
        instance = B();
    } ...

    // Run algorithm
    instance.runAlgorithm();

    return instance;
}
```

As you can see, if we have multiple different algorithms this if/switch can get pretty big. Is there a pattern to make this code easier to humanly parse (i.e., a for loop and a call) without adding an array of pairs? The question could also be expanded to "How to instantiate an input based strategy pattern?"

Do not limit to this code, as it is just an example.

Comment: You are looking for *factory pattern*.

Comment: More or less. The createStat does what the factory would do, but the factory wouldn't go further than that, which is my goal with this question.

Comment: But you will have some kind of selection anyway, `std::map`, `switch`, or `if` chains.

Comment: One approach is to use a singleton map, and every time you subclass Strategy, you register it with the map. This avoids ugly if else chains. Alternatively, the if else chains can be created easily at compile time without you needing to unroll them, but you would need to know all Strategy subclasses in advance.

Comment: I am bit lost on your comment, @linuxfever. Could you assume all subclasses are known in advance and post an answer? (if that does not help me, it might help someone else)

Comment: Did you mean std::map<std::function, singleton>, where the function is the isX() pattern matcher?

Comment: I am writing an answer, gimme a few minutes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if you know all your strategies in advance you can use a very simple meta-programming recursion to unroll your if-else chains automatically. Here we go:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <memory>

struct Strategy {
    Strategy(){}
    virtual void runAlgorithm() = 0;
};

struct A : public Strategy {

    A () {std::cout << "Creating A" << std::endl;}

    static constexpr std::string_view id(){
        return std::string_view("A");
    }

    void runAlgorithm() { /* Do A algorithm */ }
};

struct B : public Strategy {

    B () {std::cout << "Creating B" << std::endl;}

    static constexpr std::string_view id(){
        return std::string_view("B");
    }

    void runAlgorithm() { /* Do B algorithm */ }
};

struct C : public Strategy {

    C () {std::cout << "Creating C" << std::endl;}

    static constexpr std::string_view id(){
        return std::string_view("C");
    }

    void runAlgorithm() { /* Do C algorithm */ }
};

// the if else chains are constructed by recursion
template <class Head, class... Tail>
struct factory {

  static std::unique_ptr<Strategy> call(std::string id) {
      if(Head::id() == id) return std::make_unique<Head>();
      else return factory<Tail...>::call(id);
  }
};

// specialization to end the recursion
// this throws an exception, but you can adapt it to your needs
template <class Head>
struct factory<Head> {

  static std::unique_ptr<Strategy> call(std::string id) {
      if(Head::id() == id) return std::make_unique<Head>();
      else throw std::invalid_argument("The strategy id you selected was not found.");
  }
};

// here is your factory which can create instances of A,B,C based only on the runtime id
using my_factory = factory<A,B,C>;

int main() {

    auto Astrategy = my_factory::call("A");
    auto Bstrategy = my_factory::call("B");
    auto Cstrategy = my_factory::call("C");
    my_factory::call("D"); // exception thrown

}
```

Live code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55479f4df82949c5)

**Edit**

Edited to account for smart pointers and error checking as Jarod42 suggested.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems to be a good way, however I've never seen the reticences being used within the template. Could you put a link to what they are?

Comment: These are variadic templates, have a look here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Comment: Returning smart pointer would be better than raw owning pointer.

Comment: Note that you choose to default to last item when not found, `my_factory::call("D");` would return a `C`.

Comment: I will leave the question open so that more interesting answers can be raised, but I like this concept, despite the "obscurity" of the recursion. And yes, it could definitely use a smart pointer.

Comment: @DanielCarvalho: You might still merge the 2 answers: template the factory which auto registers its types. So no recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a solution for that. There are couple ways to do it. Template as in other class or this way:

```
class StrategyMaker {
public:
     void register(std::funcion<bool(char)> predicate,
                   std::function<std::unique_ptr<Strategy>(char)> factory) {
           mFactories.push_back(std::make_pair(std::move(predicate), std::move(factory)));
     }

     std::unique_ptr<Strategy> create(char ch) {
         for (auto pair & : mFactories) {
             if (pair.first(ch)) {
                 return pair.second(ch);
             }
         }
         return {};
     }

private:
     std::vector<std::pair<std::funcion<bool(char)>,
                           std::function<std::unique_ptr<Strategy>(char)>>> mFactories;
};

StrategyMaker maker;
maker.register([](char ch){ return input == 'A'; },
               [](char ch){ return std::unique_ptr(new A); });
```

Once I've seen nice article showing how to make it fully automatic. I've [found something like this](https://dev.to/fenbf/factory-with-self-registering-types--35h1) (I'm not 100% sure this is what I read some time ago).

Comment: I find this answer a little more complex than the original suggestion, as it removes encapsulation from the subclasses (although could be easily fixed). There is room for improvement here :)

Comment: This is an interesting link. Thanks for adding it to the answer!